# How to specify a non-temporal column as the “primary key” in a partitioned table?

Tags: indexing, primary-key, dolphindb, database-indexes

In DolphinDB, it seems I cannot specify a non-temporal column for the *sortColumns* of `createPartitonedTable` with the TSDB storage engine. Or is there any other way to specify a non-temporal column as the “primary key” in a partitioned table?

My table has 4 columns:

- a temporal column “DateTime“
- 2 columns of IDs: “id_key” and “id_partition”, where “id_partition“
  is the partitioning column
- a column “factor“ holding the factor values

[image]

The screenshot above shows records from the partition with *id_partition=1*. This partition has 20,000 records, and each record has a unique *id_key*. I want to make *id_key* the “primary key” of the table.

In other words, when I write a new record into the table, insert it if the value of its *id_key* does not already exist, otherwise update the existing record. Then order by the *DateTime* column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the TSDB storage engine, the use case you described is not supported. Reason:

When creating partitioned table with TSDB, set the parameter sortColumns to specify the column(s) to sort the table. The last sort column must be a temporal column; the rest of the sort columns will be combined into a "sort key", which serves as the index for sorting. As sortColumns must contain a temporal column, this doesn’t match your requirement.

It is recommended that you use the OLAP storage engine and write data to the table through [upsert!](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/u/upsert!.html):

```
dbName = "dfs://test_1123"
tbName = "test_1123"
if(existsDatabase(dbName)){
        dropDatabase(dbName)
}

//use OLAP storage engine, partition table on id_partition. no sortColumns
db = database(dbName, VALUE, `client01`client02)
colNames = `DateTime`id_key`id_partition`factor
colTypes = [DATETIME, LONG, SYMBOL, DOUBLE]
schemaTable = table(1:0, colNames, colTypes)
db.createPartitionedTable(table=schemaTable, tableName=tbName, partitionColumns=`id_partition)

//prepare test data for one partition with id_partition=1. id_key ranges from 1-20000. Insert data into the partitioned table.
data = table(2022.11.18T00:00:00 + 1..20000 as DateTime, take(1..20000, 20000) as id_key, take(`1, 20000) as id_partition, 10.5 - round(rand(1.0, 20000), 2) as factor)
pt = loadTable(dbName, tbName).upsert!(newData=data, ignoreNull=false, keyColNames=`id_key, sortColumns=`id_partition)

//use upsert! to insert a new record: id_partition=1, id_key=1, DateTime is later than the existing records.
inputOne = table(2022.11.18T00:00:00 + 30000 as DateTime, 1 as id_key, `1 as id_partition, 10.0 as factor)
pt.upsert!(newData=inputOne, ignoreNull=false, keyColNames=`id_key, sortColumns=`DateTime)
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Note:

`upsert!` inserts rows into a table if the values of the primary key do not already exist, or update them if they do. If you insert a batch of data into a table with `upsert!`, and the batch contains multiple records with duplicate keys, they will all be inserted without deduplication. For example:

```
inputOneDuplicated = table(2022.11.18T00:00:00 + 30000..30001 as DateTime, [20001, 20001] as id_key, `1`1 as id_partition, [10.0, 10.1] as factor)
pt.upsert!(newData=inputOneDuplicated, ignoreNull=false, keyColNames=`id_key, sortColumns=`DateTime)
```

result:

[image]

Therefore, before you call `upsert!`, make sure the primary key values in the batch you’re inserting are unique.